# Can Android Developer see My Google Play Account?

Tags: android

Can Android Developer see My Google Play Account, for example, email and more when I'm downloading their app or when I'm using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we can't see it through Google Developer Console even when adding a comment, so many ask to contact you directly.

Unless he requires inside the app a login with a google account or something, then by api he can "redeem" your data.

Comment: Thanks for proper answer